# Adjust camera co-ordinates to represent change in azimuth, elevation and roll values

Tags: qt, math, transform, 3d

I'm currently working with `libQGLViewer`, and I'm receiving a stream of data from my sensor, holding ***azimuth***, ***elevation*** and ***roll*** values, 3 **euler angles**.

The problem can be considered as the camera representing an aeroplane, and the changes in azimuth, elevation and roll the plane moving.

I need a general set of transformation matrices to transform the camera point and the up vector to represent this, but I'm unsure how to calculate them since the axis to rotate about changes after each rotation ( I think? ).

Either that, or just someway to pass the azimuth, elevation, roll values to the camera and have some function do it for me? I understand that `cameraPosition.setOrientation(Quaterion something)` might work, but I couldn't really understand it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example you could just take the three matrices for rotation about the coordinate axes, plug in your angles respectively, and multiply these three matrices together to get the final roation matrix (but use the correct multiplication order).

You can also just compute a quaternion from the euler angles. Look [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_representation_%28mathematics%29) for ideas. Just keep in mind that you always have to use the correct order of the euler angles (whatever your three values mean), perhaps with some experimentation (those different euler conventions always make me crazy).

**EDIT:** In response to your comment: This is accounted by the order of rotations. The matrices applied like v' = XYZv correspond to roation about z, unchanged y and then unchanged x, which is equal to x, y' and then z''. So you have to keep an eye on the axes (what your words like azimuth mean) and the order in which you rotate about these axes.

Comment: I thought that after a rotation on the x axis, you would then rotate about y', the axis that y has been mapped to, and then about z'' to get the end co-ordinate? Since it's the camera moving, and not the axis itself, don't we need to account for this somehow?

Comment: I tried to apply matrix transformation to the camera point, when I noticed that the value for elevation only had a range from -90 to +90 degrees. Is this some kinda standard? It seems to be messing with my rotation matrices.

Comment: @Chaos I'm not sure. I don't have much experience with azimuth, elevation, roll angles, as everybody seems to define them different. That's actually a general problem with euler angles, as everybody uses other conventions but assumes that his is the standard one, although you actually got at least 12 different conventions. Though those three words seem to have a special standard meaning, I'm just not sure about it. It makes sense to limit the elevation that way, although I don't know why this is a problem for you.